# Navigation (or other action) after afform submission

Tags: formbuilder

I am trying to set up a reduced entry form for new contacts to hide the complexity of the generic form and just collect the essentials. Thanks to afform_gui it is not difficult to set up the form as such and it can indeed be used to add contacts.

But: When the submit button is clicked, all I get is that tiny green notification saying “Saving…” and then “Saved” in the upper right corner of the CiviCRM window. And then nothing happens.

I would expect to be able to navigate to the contact summary view or at least clear the form so that it becomes ready for the next contact or do something else upon submission of the form but I cannot find out how. It feels like I must be missing something very basic but I just cannot figure out what it is.

Any hints anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just implemented a few days ago. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20018